# Understanding ya vs. todavía vs. aún

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, adverbios

English speakers learning Spanish have a hard time understanding the similarities and differences between *ya*, *todavía*, and *aún* (or *aun*). They don't perfectly match up with the similar English words "already," "yet," and "still." What concept exactly does each of the Spanish words express? Is there a relatively easy way for a language learner to understand the differences, or is it a matter of memorizing which word is used in which type of phrase?

Comment: In Wisconsin, too, "yet" is often used as "again" or even "more". I remember a friend talking about someone he disliked being knocked down by someone he'd insulted. "I wish he'd knock him down again yet!", he said.
And I recall an old guy watching me unload my car. He was amazed I had so much stuff and had assumed I was done when I came back for one more load. "YET??", He said.

Comment: "Ya" can also mean "soon" or "right now" (to add to the confusion).

Comment: You can't do it like this. You have to find a bunch of sample sentences in Spanish dictionaries. Rome was not built in a day. This would take an entire 10-page chapter at least. Don't memorize words. Memorize phrases or usages: Todavia no lo he hecho. I still haven't done it. The same as: No lo he hecho aun. OR Aun no lo he hecho. Tjat's a start.

Answer (score 39):

The english equivalents would be:

*Ya* = *Already*

*Todavía* = *Aún* = *Yet* = *Still*

- ***Ya** he comprado el pan* = *I have **already** bought the bread.*
- ***Todavía** no he comprado el pan* = *I **still** haven't bought the bread.*
- ***Aún** no he comprado el pan* = *I haven't bought the bread **yet**.*

*Aún* **also** means *even* (With a **meaning of time**):

***Aún** cuando había pagado, el señor no me dejó ir* = ***Even*** when I had paid, the man didn't let me go.

*Aun* is written **without accent when it doesn't mean *still*** (*Todavía*):

*No tengo tanto dinero, ¡ni **aun** la mitad!* = *I don't have that much money, not **even** half of it!*

Comment: Do you have a reference for  "Aún cuando había pagado...."? I'd have written it without the accent. But on further reflection, I wonder if both *aun* and *aún* could be correct, depending on what you're trying to say, with *aun* making your unfulfilled expectation prominent and *aún* emphasazing the sequence of events.

Comment: Good question, @MichaelWolf and I'm sorry nobody has taken a stab at answering it yet (or not via this comments section anyway), but let me give it a try. Admittedly, I had to read your question a couple of times before I could answer.  You wrote your question clearly enough, but the answer to your question is somewhat complicated.  However, after visiting this site here: https://campusvirtual.ull.es/ocw/pluginfile.php/4162/mod_resource/content/0/OA_Tilde/aun__an.html ...

Comment: @MichaelWolf  … I have come to the conclusion that when you write/say "Aún cuando había pagado", you are conveying this: "S/he/Ud. _still_ hadn't paid."  When you write/say "Aun cuando había pagado", you convey this: "S/he/Ud. hadn't _even_ paid."  The first, with accent, is equivalent to “todavía” (still).

Comment: @MichaelWolf   Complicating matters is the fact that “even” is not an exact equivalent of “still,” which corresponds better with “even now,” “even so,” or “even though.”  In the second example – aun – correlates with “even” when “even” is used as an [**intensive,***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_word_form) (WARNING: PROFANITY/STRONG LANGUAGE at this link) and this equates to the American Heritage dictionary’s meaning of “even” when used as an adverb.  (See meaning 1.b. in the 3rd edition of the American Heritage dictionary, print version.)

Comment: @MichaelWolf (and anyone else who may be interested): You didn't ask about this, but in the process of trying to figure out the differences between "aún" and "aun", I came upon the phrases "aún así" and "aun así".  As I understand it, the same meanings discussed earlier still apply, but it looks as if even native speakers get these two confused as evidenced by the fact that [**_El País_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Pa%C3%ADs) includes an entry for it in its style guide.  You can see for yourself at this link here: https://goo.gl/dhfzwx.

Comment: For anyone who may be confused or not that familiar with the use of intensifiers (in English or Spanish), this example I recently found may help clarify its meaning with respect to the adverb "aun".  If you were to see the phrase "más extraño" you would know that someone was making a comparison -- something is "stranger" relative to something else.  But someone who writes "aun más extraño" is using "aun" to intensify whatever it is they are describing.  Whatever it is that they are describing isn't just stranger, it's _much_ stranger.

Answer (score 13):

*Ya*: When a **positive** finished action is spoken. "I have already done the homework" would be "Ya he hecho los deberes".

*Todavía* and *aún*. I would say they are perfect synonyms, as everyone outlined in [this post](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=195772). But I want to note something. If I said 'todavía', I would be more likely to do the action after saying that. Also, it is expected to me to do it and I kind of deceive someone if I don't do it. If I said 'aún', which would be slightly more vague, I am just informing, not making up any excuse.

Examples: Todavía no he arreglado el cuarto. Aún no he arreglado el cuarto. The first one would be said to slightly deceive someone (sorry, I haven't tidied up my room yet); in the second, I'm just informing or complaining (I haven't tidied up my room so I cannot find anything!).

It's just my Spanish point of view. It also might depend on the region.

Comment: It sounds like the difference might be todavía = "I haven't done it yet" vs. aún = "I still haven't done it". Does that capture the distinction accurately?

Comment: "If I said 'todavía', I would be more likely to do the action after saying that."  As a native english speaker, "yet" seems different from still in the same way, in that yet implies it will happen later.

Answer (score 8):

## *Ya* = something changed

## *Todavía* = *aún* = something stayed the same

Sometimes *todavía* and *ya* map neatly onto *still/yet* and *already* respectively:

> Are you **still** here? — ***Todavía*** estás aquí?
>
> She has **yet** to do it. — ***Todavía*** tiene que hacerlo.

> He has **already** eaten. — ***Ya*** ha comido.

The trouble is that it's not always a nice 1-1 map of words. In some circumstances, the same word is used for both situations in English, and you need to ask yourself, **Has something changed (*ya*) or has something not changed (*todavía*)?**

> Has he done it **yet**? — ***Ya*** lo ha hecho? `change: not done it → done it`

> He hasn't done it **yet**. — ***Todavía*** no lo ha hecho. `no change`

This idea will also help you navigate the situations where *ya* doesn't translate neatly to one word in English - it can be used just as a marker to indicate that something has changed:

> ***Ya*** lo sé. — **Now** I know.
>
> ***Ya*** verás como te gusta. — (literally) You will see how you like it. / (figuratively) You'll come to like it. `now you don't like it, in the future you will - change`
>
> *Hacemos el ejercicio, lo corregimos, y **ya**.* — We'll do the exercise, correct it, and **then** we'll be done. `change`

---

- https://itsnachotime.com/ya/

Comment: Great answer.  I like the part about the marker.  Also the source web page does a good job of explaining about omitted words.

Comment: She has yet to do it. = She hasn't done it yet. is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

In English dialects, there are subtle differences between the meanings of one of these three words.  If you go back some seventy years, the phrase "Is he yet reading?" would have been understood differently in Ohio and in New England.

In New England, this phrase would have been understood as a stilted way of saying, "Is he reading yet?" something one would say of a child.

In Ohio, it meant, "Is he still reading?" something one would say of an old man.

The matchup for *ya*, *aún*, and *todavía* is close but not exact.  You shouldn't expect it to be exact.  With prepositions, the mismatches are even more evident.

Answer (score 3):

Ya + present tense verb = now. 
Ya voy. I go now.
Ya estoy haciendolo. I'm doing it now.

Ya + preterite verb = already. 
Ya lavé los platos. I washed the dishes already.
Ya fui a la tienda. I went to the store already.

Ya + no + present tense verb = no longer or any more. This is when you want to say you use to do something in the past but at present you're not doing it. 
Ya no estudio español. I don't study Spanish anymore.
Ya no toco la guitarra. I no longer play the guitar.

Todavia + present tense verb = still.
Todavia estás estudiando español? Are you still studying Spanish?
Todavia quiero ir a españa algún día. I still want to go to Spain some day.

Todavia + no + present or past tense verb = yet or not yet.
Todavia no lavo los platos. I haven't wash the dishes yet.
Todavia no limpié mi habitacion. I haven't cleaned my room yet.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio Don Goins!. (Puedes pegar un vistazo aquí https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/formatting  si quisieras ver formas posibles de editar el formato y hacer visualmente más eficaz tu respuesta)

Comment: In Ireland,  we use ,still,yet, and already in the normal standard ways. In the south-west we may also use "always",in the following context:" he must do it always" meaning "he has yet /still to do it", or "he has to do it yet". It comes from the Irish language and this is now an example of Hiberno-English.

Comment: Now, I go now/ I'm going now. And: I have already washed the dishes.